# Finding a conditional cumulative distribution

Tags: probability

We are given r.v X and and $Y$ and their joint density

[image]

I am asked to find $F_{X|Y}(3|4.7)$.

Well, definition of cdf, we have

$$ F_{X|Y}(3|4.7) = P(X \leq 3 | Y = 4.7) = p_{XY}(0,4.7)+p_{XY}(1,4.7)+p_{XY}(3,4.7) = 0.22$$

which contrasts with the book answer which is $1$. What is the mistake here?

Comment: It is $P(X\le 3 \mid Y=4.7) = P(X\le 3, Y=4.7) / P(Y=4.7)$.

Comment: $X$ takes values in $\{0,1,3\}$ so no matter what you condition on, it still isn't going to take a value greater than $3$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @user251257 said, you forgot to divide by $P(Y=4.7)$.